# Recurrence relation in a table

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, recursion

I am trying to generate a list of `x`-values for a function using a module, where my `x`-value must increase by 'a' if the term number is even, and by 'y' if it is odd. However, `x[1]` is `0`.

For example: $x_1 = 0, x_2 = a, x_3 = a+y, x_4 = 2a+y, x_5 = 2a+2y...$you get the point.

I am attempting to use a recurrence relation within an If-clause to generate values of $x_n$. However, my code does not work.

My code is:

```
 XValues[counter_] :=
     Module[{a, y, xvalues, x},

     x[1] -> 0;

     xvalues = 
     Table[x[j] -> If[OddQ[j] == True , x[j - 1] + y, x[j - 1] + a], {j, 2, counter}];

     Flatten@{x[1] -> 0, xvalues}
  ]
```

However, if I evaluate the module for a certain number, I get the following:

```
{ x$10387[1] -> 0, 
  x$10387[2] -> a$10387 + x$10387[1], 
  x$10387[3] -> y$10387 + x$10387[2], 
  x$10387[4] -> a$10387 + x$10387[3], 
  x$10387[5] -> y$10387 + x$10387[4]}
```

I think it is probably to do with protected variables or something along those lines, but I am not sure.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Thanks.

---------------------EDIT---------------------

Thanks for all the answers!

@Teake Nutma I have used your algorithm in a module to generate the values as it seems most appropriate to what I want to do with the `x` values.

```
XValues[counter_] :=
    Module[{xvalues},
    xsubstitute[1] = 0;
    xsubstitute[i_Integer?EvenQ] := 
    xsubstitute[i] = xsubstitute[i - 1] + a;
    xsubstitute[i_Integer?OddQ] := 
    xsubstitute[i] = xsubstitute[i - 1] + y;
    xvalues = Table[xsubstitute[i], {i, 1, counter}]
    ]
```

I now want to replace the `x` value in the `Phi` functions of the equations generated below with the `x` value generated through the XValues module (so a different value of `x` for each 'Eq' generated). This is my attempt so far but it does not appear to work. Any ideas?

```
simeqs = Table[Eq[j] -> Phi[j] == Phi[j + 1] /. x -> xsubstitute[j]/. eqs , {j, 2*number}];
```

Comment: Those $10387 etc. appear because You are scoping `a`, `x` and `y`. What do You want to get, if list of values why are You using `->`?

Comment: as an aside: another approach might be: `f[n_] := Plus @@ (Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[(n - 1)/2]] {y, a})` or similar

Comment: @PinguinDirk please, post it, I want to upvote this :)

Answer (score 3):

It is a misconception to use a recurrence table here.

I'd define simply:

```
f[n_Integer] := IntegerPart[n/2] a + IntegerPart[(n - 1)/2] y
```

then it cannot be overcome by anything else

```
f /@ Range[7]
```

> ```
> {0, a, a + y, 2 a + y, 2 a + 2 y, 3 a + 2 y, 3 a + 3 y}
> ```

**Edit**

If we prefer to generate lists automatically, this can be supplemented by

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

now it can yield appropriate parts of a table, e.g.:

```
f[ Range[2^32, 2^32 + 7] ]
```

> ```
> {2147483648 a + 2147483647 y, 2147483648 a + 2147483648 y, 
>  2147483649 a + 2147483648 y, 2147483649 a + 2147483649 y, 
>  2147483650 a + 2147483649 y, 2147483650 a + 2147483650 y, 
>  2147483651 a + 2147483650 y, 2147483651 a + 2147483651 y}
> ```

Comment: It may be a misconception but it is not a bad idea if it can be faster. :)

Comment: To see the key point try e.g. your `g[2^31+11]` and `f[2^31+11]`. In general, recurrence based solutions are elegant, but if they are unnecessary we'd better functional solutions.

Comment: If You want to compare, I should rather try `f/@Range[2^31+11]`. Don't get me wrong, Your approach is of course the best for getting single value from this sequence but OP want all the list up to `n`.

Comment: `f /@ Range[2^31, 2^31 + 11]` can generate simply partial results.

Comment: I know, I agree ;) But in case of whole list try: `g[10^5]; // Timing` and `f /@ Range[10^5]; // Timing`

Comment: @Artes Thanks for your response, your idea of defining it in a non recursive way was very helpful as it meant that I could easily access high terms of the sequence.

Comment: @CJO You are welcome. It is not only a fast way, but also a uniqe approach for huge numbers since we needn't store in RAM lower terms.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Module you could also do the following:

```
x[1] = 0

x[i_Integer?EvenQ] := x[i] = x[i - 1] + a
x[i_Integer?OddQ] := x[i] = x[i - 1] + y

xvalues = Table[x[i], {i, 1, 6}]
(* {0, a, a + y, 2 a + y, 2 a + 2 y, 3 a + 2 y} *)
```

But as @Artes [points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28519/5485), recursion doesn't make much sense performance-wise as `a` and `y` are the same at each step.

Answer (score 2):

(I am aware that this is no answer to your question, it just presents another approach to solve the problem as such - I hope it helps!)

Based on the nature of your "recurrence", you could calc directly:

```
f[n_] := Plus @@ (Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[(n - 1)/2]] {y, a})
```

Let me know if you need any explanation.

Output:

```
f /@ Range[10]
```

> {0, a, a + y, 2 a + y, 2 a + 2 y, 3 a + 2 y, 3 a + 3 y, 4 a + 3 y, 
>    4 a + 4 y, 5 a + 4 y}

Comment: It helps ;) add a line with `f /@ Range[10]`

Comment: ok thanks, and this wasn't meant to be fast or anything, just to question the recurrence :)

Comment: It is not the fastest but I like the syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest way from what I've tested so far:

```
g[i_] := Accumulate@Prepend[
                            Riffle@@(ConstantArray[##] & @@@ {{a, Ceiling[(i - 1)/2]},
                                                              {y, Floor[(i - 1)/2]}})
                            , 0];

g[10]
```

> {0, a, a + y, 2 a + y, 2 a + 2 y, 3 a + 2 y, 3 a + 3 y, 4 a + 3 y, 4 a + 4 y, 5 a + 4 y}

**Edit**

Another way for generation whole list. Similar to Teake Nutma's but quite fast.

```
h[1] = 0; sum=0;
h[x_?OddQ] := sum + y;
h[x_?EvenQ] := sum + a;
(sum = h[#]) & /@ Range[10]
```

> {0, a, a + y, 2 a + y, 2 a + 2 y, 3 a + 2 y, 3 a + 3 y, 4 a + 3 y, 4 a + 4 y, 5 a + 4 y}